# Get the nodeValues of all parent elements of element?

Tags: javascript, html, nodes

I have an HTML document, and it is structured thusly:

```
<div id="oa2">
    Content
    <div>
        Content
        <div>
        . . .
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the chain of elements may go arbitrarily deep. When there is a click on the screen, I pick it up and attempt to get the parental chain of custody for the clicked element using the following JavaScript:

```
let a=document.getElementById("oa2");
let c=[];
let d=[];
let i=[0,0,0,0];
document.onclick=function(e){
    let b=e.target;
    while(b){
        let f=b.childNodes;
        if(b==(a||document.body)){break;};
        if(!d.includes(b.id)){d[i[0]]=b.id;i[0]++;};
        while(i[3]<f.length){
            if(f[i[3]].nodeType==Node.TEXT_NODE)
            {c[i[1]]=[];c[i[1]][i[3]]=f[i[3]].nodeValue};
            i[3]++;
        };
        b=b.parentElement;
    };
    i[1]++;
    i[3]=0;
};
```

To be clear, what I want is an array (`c`) which contains arrays which contain the "path" of a child element's content and the content of each successive parent element's content. Every time there is a click on the document, I want a new child array in `c` holding the "path" of the clicked element, with out duplicates (I took care of that with `d`)..

Comment: What is the use case for this tree walker?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a while loop that checks the parent element of the target every iteration, and get an array of the path.

```
document.onclick = e => {
    let element = e.target
    const path = []
    while(element) {
        path.push(element)
        element = element.parentElement
    }
    console.log(path)
}
```

You can also check the event path property on Chrome and Firefox ( Safari has it too but it's something different

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can see now that my answer was not specific. I'll edit it now.